# CONCAT не позволяет сравнить между собой строки

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, xml

Мне необходимо сравнить ФИО в SQL запросе таблицы XML, чтоб отсеять неподходящие варианты.

Код SQL запроса сведенный к минимуму:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Patient.Surname, ' ', Patient.Name, ' ', Patient.Patronymic) Patient
FROM Patient
WHERE CONCAT(Patient.Surname, ' ', Patient.Name, ' ', Patient.Patronymic) = @GiveMePain
```

Программный код на C#:

```
private void okayButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.appointmentTableAdapter.FillByTest(this.polyclinic.Appointment, fullNameTextBox.Text);

            dataGridView.DataSource = this.polyclinic.Appointment;
        }
```

Моя БД:

[image: Скриншот базы данных "Поликлиника"]

Ожидается, что после введения ФИО в TextBox и нажатия на кнопку - ФИО будет передано в запрос, что вернет таблицу, что уже в свою очередь заполнит DataGridView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке отсеять только по имени, или если передавать ФИО раздельно и сравнивать каждое слово - все работает, но стоит использовать CONCAT, как оно ничего не возвращает.
Не хочу усложнять код, поэтому надеюсь, что это можно сделать таким способом

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Так вы конкат выражение и вашу переменную местами поменяйте. А то проверяете, что полное фио является подстрокой вашего параметра

Comment: Покажите в дополнение к своему коду значения выражений по отдельности - т.е. переместите их из WHERE в SELECT. Особенно интересно, что там в `@GiveMePain` - там действительно шаблон, или там литерал?

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Я исправил вопрос. Прошу прощения за неудобства

Comment: "все летит в тартарары" - что это значит? Не используйте непонятных фраз, формулируйте конкретно: выходит пустая выборка, или выходит такая-то ошибка.